# Footer not moving with box height

Tags: css, html, height, footer

As you can see http://jsfiddle.net/eZt4J/ I have a 6 boxes and I was wanting to know how could I make the footer sit at the bottom of them. I would like the footer to be stuck to the bottom of the page.

The template I am using is based on the boilerplate.  Please note that the `#footer` is located outside of the closing `</div>` for the `#container`

**CSS:**

```
.w960 { width:960px; margin:auto; }
#holder{width:100%;height:600px;}
#container{width:960px;margin:0px auto 40px auto; background:red;}
.third{width:260px;height:350px;float:left;}
.third li {font-size:12px;}
#first-prac, #second-prac, #fourth-prac, #fifth-prac{margin-right:80px;}
.yellow h2{line-height: 36px;border-top: 3px solid #FFB400;color: #FFB400;}
.dark h2{line-height: 36px;border-top: 3px solid #444;color: #444;}
#footer{width:100%;clear:both; height:66px;background:#2d2d2f; bottom:0;}
#footerHolder{width:960px;margin:auto;}
.foot {color:#B8BBC1;font-size:11px;margin-top:30px;}
.foot a{color:#fff;}​
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="holder">
        <div id="first-prac" class="third left yellow">
            <h2>
                Text Heading
            </h2>
            <p>
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="second-prac" class="third left dark">
            <h2>
                Text Heading
            </h2>
            <p>
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="third-prac" class="third left yellow">
            <h2>
                Text Heading
            </h2>
            <p>
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            </p>
        </div>
        <div clear="clear"></div>
        <div id="fourth-prac" class="third left dark">
            <h2>
                Text Heading
            </h2>
            <p>
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="fifth-prac" class="third left yellow">
            <h2>
                Text Heading
            </h2>
            <p>
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="six-prac" class="third left dark">
            <h2>
                Text Heading
            </h2>
            <p>
                Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
<div clear="clear"></div>
        <div id="footer" class="w960">
            <div id="footerHolder">
                <div class="foot left"><a href="#">By</a> | &copy; {{ helper:date format="Y" }} | {{ settings:site_name }}</div>
            </div>
        </div>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "not moving with box height" you're referring to the content stretching past the footer container, you should just be able to add `overflow: hidden` to your #container CSS. This will clear the floated items in the #container and push the footer past them.

This will however cut your `.third` containers short since you've defined a static `height: 350px` for that class. Just remove the `height` from this class if you want the column height to be flexible.

As is with overflow: 
http://jsfiddle.net/eZt4J/2/

With .third static height removed:
http://jsfiddle.net/eZt4J/3/

Comment: Thanks,`.third` I changed it to min-height and now it works across both pages

Answer (score 0):

Google 'sticky footer'. This is a good example:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: Kevin Instead of #wrap would I use my #container?

Comment: I can't see all of your HTML, but likely yes. The example provided should give you a clue to the required HTML structure and relevant CSS.